# Stored procedure for updating values dynamically in db2 table

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic, db2

I am trying to update the values of a table dynamically, using stored procedure. My stored procedure is as follows,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Update
    (
     IN ID1 BIGINT,
     IN SOURCE1 VARCHAR(100),
     IN NAME1 VARCHAR(100)
     ) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    UPDATE MessageTable
    SET SOURCE=SOURCE1,
    NAME=NAME1
    WHERE ID=ID1;     
END
```

When I try to pass the value for ID1 and SOURCE1 alone, the values are not getting updated. When I pass all the three values, they are getting updated properly. My requirement is even if I pass two values it should get updated. I tried giving DEFAULT NULL for the arguments. Since the fields are declared NOT NULL, it was not working. Could someone help to overcome this. The stored procedure should work even if I pass single value. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE MessageTable
SET SOURCE = COALESCE(SOURCE1, SOURCE),
    NAME   = COALESCE(NAME1, NAME)
WHERE ID = ID1;
```

When `NAME1` is `NULL` then the original `NAME` will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You could check with `IF` or another statement whether all arguments have non-NULL values and then switch to either an `UPDATE` statement that sets one or two column values.

Comment: I have around twenty arguments to be passed. Right now I am just testing with three parameters.

Comment: Then the proposed solution using `COALESCE` is better.